# tableView set editing of menuController Action not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uimenucontroller

I have a tableView and tableViewCell. I create the MenuController to setTableView editing. But it seems fail. But I use navigation button add action that "testFunc" . it works to change mutiselected editing. What do I miss to think about it? I already addsubview of tableView. And I also follow UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate.

```
protocol DelegateA {
func testFunc()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,DelegateA { 

lazy var tableView:UITableView = { ()->UITableView in
    let ui:UITableView = UITableView()
    ui.delegate = self
    ui.dataSource = self
    ui.separatorStyle = .none
    ui.backgroundColor = defaultBackgroundColor
    return ui
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
}

func testFunc() {

    print("123") //it print "123" successful

    //not working
    if(self.tableView.isEditing == false) {
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated:true)
    }
    else {
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated:true)
    }
}

}
```

this is the label of customized tableViewCell

```
class UITalkContent:UILabel {

var delegate:DelegateA?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    numberOfLines = 0
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureLongPress)))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: defaultContentPadding, left: defaultPadding, bottom: defaultContentPadding, right: defaultPadding)
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

func gestureLongPress(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.state == .ended) {
        return
    }

    becomeFirstResponder()


    let menu = UIMenuController.shared


    menu.menuItems = [
        UIMenuItem(title: localString(string: "FORWARD"), action: #selector(forward)),
    ]


    menu.setTargetRect(bounds, in: self)


    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

func forward(menu :UIMenuController ) {
    print("321") //print "321" successfully 
    self.delegate = ViewController()
    self.delegate?.testFunc()

}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(forward)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = text
}
}
```

2017.06.16 update

```
class ContentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var labelContent:UILabel = { ()->UILabel in
    let ui:UILabel = UITalkContent()
    ui.textColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.20, blue:0.20, alpha:1.00)
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    ui.font = defaultTextFont
    ui.numberOfLines = 0
    ui.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping
    ui.layer.cornerRadius = defaultButtonRadius
    ui.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ui.isHidden = false
    return ui
}()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    loadContent()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    loadVFL()
}

func loadContent() {
    contentView.addSubview(labelContent)
}

func loadVFL() {
    labelContent.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    labelContent.sizeToFit() 

}
}
```

[image: mutiselected tableview like this.]

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to know is actually unclear and vague. But I can see here ***you are doing `protocol-delegation` in wrong way***. For making this process right, follow steps below:

1. Create a **protocol** in your sender class, from where you want to pass any message (in your case: `UITalkContent`)

   ```
   protocol MyProtocol {
       func testFunc()
   }
   class UITalkContent: UILabel {...}
   ```
2. Add a `delegate` *var* in your sender class as:

   ```
   class UITalkContent: UILabel {
       var delegate: MyProtocol?
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Use this `delegate` *var* to call the method that you specified in your protocol. This must be done in your sender class and at the time when you are ready to send any message. In your case it's the `func forward(menu:)`

   ```
   class UITalkContent: UILabel {
       ...
       ...
       func forward(menu :UIMenuController ) {
           ...
           ...
           delegate.testFunc()
       }
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Adopt the protocol in your recieving class (in your case: `ViewController`)

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
5. Implement the protocol's method inside receiving class. Program control will be transferred here when notification happens.

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
       ...
       ...
       func testFunc() {
           // do what you want to do when program control reaches here
       }
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
6. Now you have to set the receiving class as the `delegate` of that sender class. For this you have to assign `self` (receiving class) to the instance of the sender class. (But I don't see any instance of your `UILabel`)

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
       ...
       ...
       `instance of UILabel` = self
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello, @nayem my instance of UITalkContent is write in TableViewCell. And What should I do about step 6 ? I also update my question about tableviewCell.

Comment: Okay. You have a pretty complex implementation. What are you trying to achieve actually? ___Should your label inform your ViewController of something?___

Comment: I feel it's complex, too. I add GestureRecognizer to label, Then it show menuController. Click menu action let TableView Mutiselected. I update image.